# Navigation title not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a tableviewcontroller added and segue to detailTableViewcontroller. Both embedded in navigation controller

I want to change title of my DetailTableViewController to "Financial Summary" like below screen. How can I do that. I tried below code but it didn't work

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Financial Summary"
```

and topItem.title is for navigating back
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Back"

Please advice how I can set "Financial Summary" title[image]

Comment: You're not providing enough info.

Comment: `navigationController` is an optional. Check with the debugger to see whether it is nil. If that's the case, you are not changing the title in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this by just setting the following on the `DetailViewController`:

`navigationItem.title = "Financial Summary"`

You would want to make sure this is invoked before the view controller is displayed. You can learn more about how navigation controllers work by reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

Specifically, this section is pertinent here:

> If no custom title view is set, the navigation bar displays a label containing the view controller’s default title. The string for this label is usually obtained from the title property of the view controller itself. If you want to display a different title than the one associated with the view controller, set the title property of the view controller’s navigation item instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are setting the title for the NavigationViewController and not your DetailViewController.

To accomplish what you want, you need to set the title in `DetailViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`, you will want to do something like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "Financial Summary"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `Navigation Title` as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Financial Summary"
  }
```

Hope this Works Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Financial Summary"

  }
```